# Position of Indirect object in German questions

Tags: dative, pronoun, standard-german, question, personal-pronoun

In the sentence, "Woher hat sie die Schuhe?" which means "Where does she have the shoes from?", shouldn't the pronoun *sie* take the dative case? As *Die Schuhe* is the direct object, it is taking the Accusative case. The dative case of the pronoun *she* is *ihr* in German; therefore, wouldn't the correct sentence will be "Woher hast ihr die Schuhe?"

I got this example from [here](https://youtu.be/q9DRcIb1iRI?t=260).

I am still a student in the German language, therefore, I know that I am wrong with my idea, but I want to understand the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is wrong in multiple respects.

First of all the sentence should read

> Woher **hat** sie die Schuhe?
> (*hast* is 2nd person singular)

The terms *direct and indirect object* are sometimes used to make explanations for English natives easier to understand. But in fact there is nothing like direct and indirect object in German.

But let's have a look at your sentence:

If you turn the question

> Woher hat sie die Schuhe?

into a statement

> Sie hat die Schuhe (von ihrer Schwester).

you see clearly that

- **Sie** is the subject
- **die Schuhe** is one object
- **(von ihrer Schwester)** is another object

The subject is always in nomative case. So *sie* is right.

*Die Schuhe* is in accusative case and here it wouldn't be totally wrong to compare it to the English direct object.

And finally there is another object (dative case) and that's exactly what the question is asking for.

*Woher* asks for something in dative case.

---

Regarding the title of your question: In German there is no way to indentify the case of an object by its position in the sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "hast" spelling was a mistake by my side, it was a typo that I forgot the correct. I understand now, thanks.

Comment: To me, it's better to just dispense with the English-centric "direct object" and "indirect object" altogether and use different terminology for German. I prefer "accusative object" and "dative object". Otherwise it's hopeless trying to understand the structure of even simple sentences such as *Mir ist heiß* and *Die Schuhe gefallen mir.*

Comment: I think it should be "So *sie* is right." instead of *she*. Maybe it's worth to mention that *she* is the subject also in the English translation .

Comment: @Bodo You're right of course. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know much grammar, but I don’t think that it is good to call an object (is it even an object?) with a preposition (‘von’) a dative object.

Comment: @CarstenS You have a point. I think, *von ihrer Schwester* is a *Präpositionalobjekt*. But that's not part of the original sentence. The answer to the example question could also be: *geerbt*, *auf dem Dachboden gefunden*, ...  *Woher* is just the trickiest question word in terms of grammar.